# Nexus S - Can't copy to SD card

Tags: files

When I connect my Nexus S to my computer I can see various files (media, LOST.DIR, DCIM...). If I copy a file here, I can't find it on the file manager (ASTRO) on my phone? How do I access these files on my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've disconnected from the computer and the phone has remounted the card, then navigate to `/sdcard/` or `/mnt/sdcard/`.   (On other Samsung phones like the Galaxy S, you would go to `/sdcard/external_sd/`.)

Comment: I cannot see that directory on my phone (using Windows 7 to browse). When I browse to /sdcard/ on my phone, it is empty, so it isn't the same folder I'm seeing on my computer.

Comment: @Casebash Hmm, weird.  Have you tried `/mnt/sdcard/`?  Have you ensured that the SD card was properly remounted by the phone after you disconnected from the computer?

Comment: Oh, I need to disconnect from the computer before accessing the card on my phone again

Comment: @Casebash Righto. I've updated the answer with that to hopefully help someone else out in the future.  Glad you got it sorted!